# Drag and Drop file download from Website/Browser to local filesystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download, drag-and-drop

we are using jquery in our project and we were thinking about to implement a function for offering a drag and drop download from our website to the local underlying file system (Desktop for example...).
I found some useful links but all of the seem to be outdated:

http://ankurm.com/html-5-dnd-download-a-quick-implementation/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/box_dnd_download/

https://www.salesking.eu/blog/coding/jquery-plugin-to-drag-files-from-browser-onto-desktop/

My questions:

1. Does anybody knows a overview of Browsers and their versions which support this feature?
   I read its a part of HTML5 but not every HTML5 browser is supporting this feature. More worse: in one of these links users wrote some Browsers were supporting this feature but after a while the support was removed...
2. Does anybody knows a up-to-date howto how to implement it "nowadays"?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Pretty much Chrome and Opera these days, most API filesystem support was removed from other browsers and the standard is going to pretty much defunct.